# web page loading is too slow when using webview tag in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

Electron is running the web page using  tag in index.html. The problem is that there is no problem when accessing the page in Chrome, but it is very slow when running with electron. Even when I look at the developer tool's network tab, all resources are slowly downloading. Interestingly, the electron app is working normally with the fiddler program running. What's the problem?
 `<webview ng-style="style" id="content" autosize="on" allowpopups src="https://test.com"></webview>`

`app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-gpu-blacklist'); app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-gpu-rasterization'); app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-zero-copy');`

I tried this code, but it didn't work